# Sort a List<T> by another List<T>

Tags: c#, linq

My model is:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

I have two collections. And I would like to sort `toBeSortedList` like `etalonList`:

```
List<Person> etalonList = new List<Person>()
{
     new Person() { Id=10, Name="Jon"},
     new Person() { Id=4, Name="Ben"},
     new Person() { Id=11, Name="Magnus"},
     new Person() { Id=8, Name="Joseph"},
};

List<Person> toBeSortedList = new List<Person>()
{
     new Person() { Id=11, Name="Magnus"},
     new Person() { Id=4, Name="Ben"},                
     new Person() { Id=10, Name="Jon"},
     new Person() { Id=8, Name="Joseph"},
};
```

I've tried:

```
var orderedByIdList = tobeSortedList.OrderBy(x => etalonList.IndexOf(x.Id));
```

But I've met a such error:

> cannot convert from 'int' to 'SOConsoleApplication.Person'

Maybe you have another suggestions?

Comment: tobeSortedList.OrderBy(x => etalonList.IndexOf(x.Id)).ToList();

Comment: @CodeConstruct This won't work either.

Comment: You have to cast this to a Class (Person)

Comment: @CodeConstruct You completely misunderstand the question I'm afraid. Just running `ToList` isn't going to fix the error.

Comment: Why not just reuse etalonList, or copy it? As the question is stated now, sorting toBeSortedList would just end up with it holding the same values in the same order as etalonList.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first create a dictionary from `etalonList` in order to speed up sorting:

```
int index;
var etalonDictionary = etalonList.ToDictionary(k => k.Id, v => index++);
```

Then find back the ID from the dictionary and use that for sorting:

```
var sortedList = toBeSortedList.OrderBy(x => etalonDictionary[x.Id]).ToList();
```

Comment: If you're using a hash table anyway, you can also easily avoid sorting at all. Create a dictionary from toBeSortedList, and then use `etalonList.Select(p => dict[p.Id])`

Answer (score 2):

[`List.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb(v=vs.110).aspx) takes the object as argument and returns the index of it. You are passing an `int`-value which is the `Id`. That doesn't compile.

You could override `Equals`+`GethashCode` and pass `x` instead of `x.Id`. But I would prefer [`List.FindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k601hd9(v=vs.110).aspx) in this case:

```
 var orderedByIdList = toBeSortedList
    .OrderBy(x => etalonList.FindIndex(p => p.Id == x.Id));
```

Here's the override `Equals` approach which enables to use `IndexOf`:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(ReferenceEquals(obj, this))
            return true;
        Person other = obj as Person;
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        return other.Id == this.Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id;
    }
}
```

Now this works too:

```
var orderedByIdList = toBeSortedList
    .OrderBy(x => etalonList.IndexOf(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that some values in `etalonList` are not present in `toBeSortedList` because in all other cases the question makes no sense:

1. `toBeSortedList` has elements not included in `etalonList`. In this case the problem is underspecified; how would you order these new list members?
2. `toBeSortedList` contains exactly the same members `etalonList` has. In that case simply return `etalonList` or duplicate it.

A naive, but simple way to order `toBeSortedList` is the following (note that I am assuming that case 1 is not possible):

```
static IEnumerable<T> OrderBy(this IEnumerable<T> list, IEnumerable<T> guideList)
{
    foreach (var member in guideList)
    {
        if (toBeSortedList.Contains(member))
            yield return member;
    }
}

var orderedList = toBeSortedList.OrderBy(etalonList).ToList();
```

Doesn't perform all that well but if lists are not very long, it should do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular sort in this case at all. You can simply [join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) the etalon with target and project the target elements. If the etalon does not contain all the targets, you can concatenate the non existing items either at the beginning or at the end of the sorted sequence, eventually applying some additional order.

In both cases, you'll end up with a fast O(N) time complexity operation.

Here is the LINQ that puts the non existing items at the end:

```
var orderedByIdList =
    (from a in etalonList join b in toBeSortedList on a.Id equals b.Id select b)
    .Concat
    (from a in toBeSortedList join b in etalonList on a.Id equals b.Id into b where !b.Any() select a)
    .ToList();
```